# Google App Engine - GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, jsonFactory) Not Found

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I need to use Google Cloud Storage from Google App Engine. So for this, I am trying to use Application Default Credentials to get authorization credentials to connect to Cloud Storage API. I added the Google Cloud Storage JSON API in eclipse using add Google Api option. It added google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar. This jar does not have below method.

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, jsonFactory);
```

When I see the Samples I see below dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-storagetransfer</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev1-1.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But in eclipse, while using add Google API window, I do not see a way to find this "v1-rev1-1.20.0" version of Google Cloud Storage API. How can I download the Google Cloud Storage API jars which are compatible to version v1-rev1-1.20.0?

Comment: You don't need GoogleCredential. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are accessing Cloud Storage from App Engine, you can use GCS client built for App Engine:

```
GcsService gcsService = GcsServiceFactory.createGcsService();
// ...
ListResult objects = fileService.list(MY_BUCKET_NAME, ListOptions.DEFAULT);
// ... and so on
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue for time being. Saved a lot of time. But as a long term solution, I had to convert the project to a maven project and use the Latest App Engine Java SDK 1.9.42. Earlier I was using 1.9.25 SDK. Using the latest SDK solved the actual error of not identifying the below API was resolved. GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault(transport, jsonFactory);